# Java Generics bounded type doesn't apply to method parameters

Tags: java, generics, extends

I have these (simplified) classes:

```
public abstract class BaseDataSource<T extends BaseDbPojo> {

    public abstract List<T> getAllEntities();
    public abstract boolean deleteEntity(T t);
}

public class TestsDataSource extends BaseDataSource {

    @Override
    public List<Test> getAllEntities() {...}

    @Override
    public boolean deleteEntity(Test t) {...}
}
```

Where `Test` extends `BaseDbPojo`.

Now, `getAllEnities()` is all good - it is recognized as a valid override for its super abstract method.
`deleteEntity(Test t)` on the other hand - is not, and any other method that accepts a derived type of `BaseDbPojo` raises compliation error.

My IDE (InteliJ) suggested:

```
@Override
public boolean deleteEntity(BaseDbPojo baseDbPojo) {...}
```

Which is obviously not what I want - I want the method to receive a subclass of `BaseDbPojo` - `Test` in our case.

If I declared `<T extends BaseDbPojo>` in the class scope, why does the compiler respect that only as a method return type and not as a method parameter?

Comment: should be `extends BaseDataSource<Test>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing the type parameter in the `extends` clause for `TestsDataSource`.  Without it you are extending the raw `BaseDataSource`, which means that `T` undergoes type erasure to become `Object`.  Supply a type argument for `T` -- `Test` -- in the `extends` clause.

```
class TestsDataSource extends BaseDataSource<Test> {
```